# How can I center an image in Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am struggling to center an image using only Bootstrap's CSS-classes. I already tried several things. One was adding Bootstrap CSS-class `mx-auto` to the `img` element, but it does nothing.

Help is appreciated.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4 mx-auto">
            <img class=""...> <!-- center this image within the column -->

            <form...>

            <p...>
            <p...>
            <p...>                
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 178, accepted):

Image by default is displayed as inline-block, you need to display it as block in order to center it with `.mx-auto`. This can be done with built-in `.d-block`:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
            <img class="mx-auto d-block" src="...">  
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or leave it as inline-block and wrapped it in a div with `.text-center`:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
          <div class="text-center">
            <img src="..."> 
          </div>     
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wpL1gp0b/17/) showing both ways. 
They are documented [here](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/content/images/#aligning-images) as well.

Answer (score 30):

Since the img is an inline element, Just use `text-center` on it's container. Using `mx-auto` will center the container (column) too.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4 mx-auto text-center">
        <img src="..">
    </div>
</div>
```

By default, images are `display:inline`. If you only want the **center the image** (and not the other column content), make the image `display:block` using the **`d-block`** class, and then `mx-auto` will work.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4">
    <img class="mx-auto d-block" src="..">
  </div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://codeply.com/go/iakGGLdB8s

Answer (score 19):

## **3** ways to align `img` in the center of its parent.

### 1.

`img` is an inline element, `.text-center` aligns inline elements in center if the element its used on, is a `block` element.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container mt-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col text-center">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/8/80/Wikipedia-logo-v2.svg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### 2.

`.mx-auto` centers `block` elements. In order to so,  change the `display` of the img from `inline` to `block` using the `.d-block` class.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container mt-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/8/80/Wikipedia-logo-v2.svg" alt="" class="img-fluid d-block mx-auto">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### 3.

Use `.d-flex` and `.justify-content-center` on its parent.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container mt-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/8/80/Wikipedia-logo-v2.svg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The last approach worked best for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The Bootstrap class `.center-block` works well.