# How to center the image in bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, image, twitter-bootstrap-4

I am new to Bootstrap 4, earlier in Bootstrap 3 we use class "center-block", now I am not able to find this in new version.

Comment: Read https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#utilities

Answer (score 9):

Center an inline element has nothing to do with Bootstrap actually.

### Center the image using `text-align`

An image is an inline element and can be aligned using `text-align`.

Text will flow around the image, since it is an inline element.

Normally:

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
</div>
```

The Bootstrap way:

```
<div class="text-center">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
</div>
```

### Center the image using `margin`

You can change the display of the image to a block element and use margin to center the block.

Text will be pushed above and under the image since we change the display to `block`.

```
<div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" style="display: block;margin: auto;" />
</div>
```

The Bootstrap way:

```
<div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" class="mx-auto d-block" />
</div>
```

### Full example

```css
.my-text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.my-block-center {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="my-text-center">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
</div>

<div class="text-center">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
</div>

<div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" class="my-block-center" />
</div>

<div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" class="mx-auto d-block" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

This can be done with built-in .d-block:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
            <img class="mx-auto d-block" src="...">  
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

More info in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43226511/how-can-i-center-an-image-in-bootstrap-v4-alpha)

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for.

Comment: Worked charmly for my case too. But I think it lacks a bit of an explanation. How that works ?

Comment: Image by default is displayed as inline-block, you need to display it as block in order to center it with .mx-auto. This can be done with built-in .d-block. In the link is the original answer

Comment: yes. you did it.

Answer (score -1):

Try using this code.

html:

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 centered">
                        <img alt="Bootstrap Image Preview" src="http://lorempixel.com/140/140/" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

css:

```
centerd{

        text-align: center;

    }
```