# How to center the object with lightbox using bootsrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I use Polo - Responsive Multi-Purpose HTML5 Template.
I can't center my object

I did try many solutions, and nothing work for me still on left side.

See screenshot

[image]

```html
<!--Single image lightbox -->
<div class="hr-title hr-long center"><abbr>Single image lightbox</abbr> </div>
<div class="row col-no-margin">


  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="grid-item">
      <div class="grid-item-wrap">
        <div class="grid-image"> <img alt="Image Lightbox" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200" /> </div>
        <div class="grid-description">
          <a title="Paper Pouch!" data-lightbox="image" href="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200" class="btn btn-light btn-rounded">Zoom</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--Single image lightbox -->
  <hr class="space">
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I center an image in Bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43226511/how-can-i-center-an-image-in-bootstrap)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is not the only solution, this is a suggestion :)

You can just use class `offset-md-4` combined with `text-center` and it should work.

Also think about mobile. I have added `offset-2` and `col-8` to make sure it looks good on small screen too.

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="hr-title hr-long center">
  <abbr>Single image lightbox</abbr>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row col-no-margin">
    <div class="offset-2 col-8 offset-md-4 col-md-4 text-center">
      <div class="grid-item">
        <div class="grid-item-wrap">
          <div class="grid-image"> <img alt="Image Lightbox" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200" /></div>
          <div class="grid-description">
            <a title="Paper Pouch!" data-lightbox="image" href="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200" class="btn btn-light btn-rounded">Zoom</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--Single image lightbox -->
<hr class="space">
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below CSS to center align the image

```css
img {
  margin-left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<!--Single image lightbox -->
<div class="hr-title hr-long center"><abbr>Single image lightbox</abbr> </div>
<div class="row col-no-margin">


  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="grid-item">
      <div class="grid-item-wrap">
        <div class="grid-image"> <img alt="Image Lightbox" src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x400" /> </div>
        <div class="grid-description">
          <a title="Paper Pouch!" data-lightbox="image" href="images/mockup/1.jpg" class="btn btn-light btn-rounded">Zoom</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--Single image lightbox -->
<hr class="space">
```

Comment: That would center the image in the `div` but it would not solve the issue that the whole div is on the left.

Comment: @ Daut  he never mentioned that he wants the whole div on the center. before down voting you should read the question 1st. He only said `object` and object could me anything. so please make it 0.

Comment: Edit your answer to say that, if you give a particular solution explain it :)

Answer (score -1):

Instead of 
`<div class="col-md-4">`

Do the following:

`<div class="col-md-12 text-center">`

`.text-center` is the bootstrap class which will center the image with respect to the column

`.col-md-12` will imply there is only 1 column in the entire row

Comment: could you provide a JS fiddle with your problem and give more data instead of just down voting an answer!?

Comment: I dont think that making the div full width makes any difference especially since it contains only 1 column which he wants to be centered. Atleast with my solution you dont need to add additional classes unlike your own to support mobile screens. Much more readable and understandable too!