# Center img in Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I tried using mx-auto to center an image inside a Bootstrap 4 card just below the ard-text but the image is left-justified still.

```
img src="my.svg" class="mx-auto" alt="...">
```

I tried to put the img inside a div then text-center but did not work.

How do you center it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mx-auto d-block`

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <img class="mx-auto d-block" src="...">  
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43226511/how-can-i-center-an-image-in-bootstrap<br) for more

**[Live example on Codeply](https://www.codeply.com/p/OfZjsCnmSD)**

Comment: d-block effect on mx-auto is confusing.

Comment: @JuanTamad - What happened?

Comment: it worked, just need to understand why adding d-block centered img, thanks.  Now I have to figure out how to center the Bootstrap card itself, I can use container class but that would be nested containers.

Comment: @JuanTamad - Read the following article. `d-block` is a display property of bootstrap. 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/

Comment: Visible on all .d-block, I think it's the default.

Answer (score 0):

Just need to add a class .center-block in the img tag, looks like this

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span4"></div>
    <div class="span4"><img class="center-block" src="picture.png"/></div>
    <div class="span4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In Bootstrap already has css style call .center-block

```
.center-block {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
 }
```

You can see a sample from [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vxad5/1/)

If it doesn't work then use Use `mx-auto d-block`

Comment: center-block doesn't work.