# i can't center image in bootstrap row

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Here is my code: image is not centering top and bottom , i tried all google methods.
i have added img-fluid and img-thumbnail both also used my-auto . normal margin like margin: 10% working only auto is not working.

```
 <div class="intro">
       <div class="row">
        <div class="col-10 col-md-12 col-lg-6">   
        <img class=" img-fluid " src="./img/l-intro-img.jpg" alt="l-intro-img"/>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6">
        <h1>Random text</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

```
.intro {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: url(../img/bg-intro.svg);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: auto;
}

.img-fluid {
  display: block;
  margin: auto 0px;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I center an image in Bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43226511/how-can-i-center-an-image-in-bootstrap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution to your problem:

```css
.intro {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: url(https://source.unsplash.com/random/560x560);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.img-fluid {
  display: block;
  margin: auto 0px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="intro">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-6  d-flex justify-content-center align-items-centerr">
        <img class=" img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x154" alt="l-intro-img" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-6 text-center">
        <h1 class="text-white">Random text</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

You may want to find this in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/richierich25/owzsvfd3/27/)

Answer (score 0):

you are using image in Background, so your have to be more specific with the div size and image size you are using, for avoiding this problem use these two properties
1* background-position-x:50%;
2* background-positon-y:50%;

Comment: added both in .intro class, still margin auto not working

Answer (score 0):

Use `background-size: contain;` to align center.

```
.intro {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: url(../img/bg-intro.svg);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

Please include  `mx-auto text-center` class to div above the image.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="intro">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-10 col-md-12 col-lg-6 mx-auto text-center">   
      <img class="img-fluid " src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/quhig.png" alt="l-intro-img"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 text-center">
      <h1>Random text</h1>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: i need to center img-fluid image

Comment: Try now the demo bro :)